# Calculating outgoing traffic for videos based on views, resolution and filesize

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a video portal and I want to calculate the passed outgoing traffic for videos based on views, resolution and filesize in my adminCP. My problem is if I have many rows in my videoviews table, php is exiting with a memory limit fatal error (512M memory limit). And now I'm needing the best practice or best solution to calculate/handle that.

This is how my videoviews table looks like:

```
|----vwid----|--vid--|--------resolution--------|
|Videoview ID|VideoID|Resolution of viewed video|
```

(there are 3 not relevant to this question columns)

The filesize is different for every video and resolution and needs to get fetched from the filesystem per stat(), that's why I can't just take one and multiply it with the count of views.

My next try after fetching every row and adding the filesize for the individual file was fetching only a fixed count of rows per for-continuous (like 10'000). But this resulted not in a different way than the first try.

After that I tried to count the views for every resolution for every video, but this resulted in a very slow query (35s) and I discarded that idea.

Currently I have 3 millions rows in my views table for test purposes (they get randomly added every day), so I need a good solution for a high count of rows.

Now is the question if you guys have any idea to do this better? If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask.

Explain Query:

```
 SELECT vid, resolution, COUNT(*) FROM videoviews GROUP BY vid, resolution
```

Output:

```
 id     select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
 1  SIMPLE  anitube_videoviews  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3126686     Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: It sounds like you're doing the heavy lifting (the math regarding the total bandwidth) in PHP.  You really should make your database do that work and have it simply return the results.  I can tell you that calculating it manually in PHP will be much slower if it weren't dying to memory limits.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Now is the question how I can make the database doing that work.

Comment: How long does the following query take: `SELECT vid, resolution, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY vid, resolution`?

Comment: @Mr.Llama 17.9 seconds

Comment: Yikes... nearly 20 seconds.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN on your SQL statements do see what they are doing, and add appropriate indexes where missing. (And go _research_ that topic please, of those keywords don’t mean anything to you yet.)

Comment: @CBroe I've already added indexes to the releveant rows, since I found out one was missing at my first attempt. I'll leave the  EXPLAIN output in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should think about a different approach. Your solution would compute the result based on *potential views* - so if I would refresh the page 5 times (for a 1GB Video file), I would have produced 5 GB of traffic within a split second - which I didn't.

Storing the View-Duration as Peter suggested is *better* - but still not accurate. The file might have been completely downloaded already, but the user only viewed 3 minutes. So you would track less traffic.

So, rather than relying on the resolution and viewcount or view-duration, you should keep track of the bytes *actually* beeing transfered to a clients computer to receive accurate results.

---

One possible way of achieving this, would be to avoid direct links on the file, but deliver them using a php-script file, which can keep track of the transfered volume.

The following snippet will provide such a functionality. Note, that for a server with a huge amount of users, you shouldn't use such a big chunk size - or you will run out of memory shortly :-)

The following file can be stored as `getFile.php` and called by passing the file-id, like `getFile.php?id=25565`. (Having such a `getFile.php` also provides the advantage that you don't need to make files *visible* to the web - in your `getFile.php`, you can check for login again, and restrict unauthorized access.)

```
$file = resolveIdToActualFilePath($_GET["id"]);

set_time_limit(0);

//Important: we catch that manually to determine transfered bytes.
ignore_user_abort(true); 

ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: video/mp4'); //set depending on format.
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"'); 
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

// Repeat reading until EOF
$chunk = 1024 * 1024; // bytes per chunk (1 MB)
$fh = fopen($file, "rb");
while (!feof($fh)) { 
    echo fread($fh, $chunk);
    flush();
    ob_flush();

    //catch user abort manually.
    if (connection_status() != 0){
        //abort or timeout. Store already transfered amount to database.
        //here an error of one time chunk size might appear, cause it has been read, but not delivered.
        file_put_contents("test.txt", "Aborted after: ".(ftell($fh)+1)." Bytes.");
        fclose($fh);
        exit; 
    }
}

//pointer pos + 1 = actual bytes transfered - write to database.
$bytesTransfered = ftell($fh) +1; 
file_put_contents("test.txt", "Download complete after ".$bytesTransfered." Bytes");
fclose($fh);
exit;
```

Depending on how you are storing the transfered bytes, The query becomes quite simple - and fast.

I would recommend you a table like this, to maintain all information you ever need for evaluation purpose:

```
id | fileId | userId | bytes | dateTimeStart       | dateTimeEnd         | status   
1    2256     158      15454   2014-12-27 18:45:20   2014-12-27 18:52:17   COMPLETE
2    1123     122      185     2014-12-27 19:00:00   2014-12-27 19:00:02   ABORT
3    12355    112      13365   2014-12-27 20:45:20   2014-12-27 20:45:36   COMPLETE
```

This would allow to also determine which files are aborted how often, whats the average download
speed of a user (assuming your server is not the bottleneck), what's your peak-upload rate in given times, what's the average load etc. pp.

Having the table well indexed, queries like this should run in no time:

```
SELECT SUM(bytes) WHERE fileId = 1123; --traffic per file
SELECT SUM(bytes) WHERE userId = 189; -- traffic per user
SELECT SUM(bytes) WHERE DATE(dateTimeStart) = CURDATE(); -- traffic today
SELECT SUM(bytes) WHERE fileId = 1123 AND DATE(dateTimeStart) = CURDATE(); -- traffic today for file 1123.
SELECT SUM(bytes) WHERE dateTimeStart >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY): -- traffic within last 7 days.
```

Using a (unsigned) Bigint on the bytes column would allow you to sum traffic up to `9223372036854775807` bytes, which is 8 ExaBytes. (8192 PetaByte) (Currently worldwide internet traffic is  27,48 PetaByte per Month - so you should be good for a while unless you host the whole internet :) )

Answer (score 0):

There could be several approaches to this problem:

**Store size in videos table**

I see `VideoID` column, this means you have videos table, you can add column `size default 0` to it and create simple php script to populate it, like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
do {
    data = 'select * from `videos` where `size` = 0 limit 1000'; // select any reasonable limit here
    foreach row in data {
        file_size = fstat(filename)
        update `videos` set `size` = ??? where `videoid` = ???
    }
} while (sizeof(rows) > 0);
```

check whether you have indexes:

1. videos: videoid, size
2. viedeoviews: videoid

then you will be able to run query like:

```
select sum(a.`size`) as totalsize
from `videos` as a inner join `videoviews` as b on (a.`videoid` = b.`videoid`)
```

of course during upload of new video or alteration of old one - you need to update `size` to actual one

**Save actual aggregated stats**

You can create separate table, where you store actual traffic, like this:

```
create table `stats` (
    `resolution` varchar(...) primary key,
    `total_size` bigint
);
```

during each view - update this table like

```
update `stats` set `total_size` = `total_size` + ??? where `resolution` = ???;
```

of course you will miss old data, but you can populate it with similar approach as in first solution (just select all views before you started stats population)

PS. in any case I suggest you to populate videos table with size to avoid filesystem query

Answer (score 0):

i Think you should add a view_duration field in that table, and run a query like the following:

```
SELECT resolution, SUM(view_duration) FROM videoviews WHERE vwid>0 GROUP BY resolution
```

The above should give you the total time of all views per resolution. The outgoing traffic for you would be the bytes_per_second * sum_of_duration_of_view(in seconds) for each resolution and video format. https://documentation.apple.com/en/motion/usermanual/index.html#chapter=B%26section=2%26tasks=true